# list view not shown over main fragment having map

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

i am showing map in main content view which is a fragment. i want to show a listView over the main content view having map on a button click in an action bar or swipe the screen from left. i have tried alot but all in vain. my problem is how can i show the listview over the main content fragment such that the list view comes over the map.

upto now the listview appears when i swipe but it appears below the map in the fragment

i hav'nt add the functionality for clicking the button in actionbar. i am just swiping the list view from left. thanks in advance

my code is

DrawerClass.java

public class DrawerClass extends Activity {

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
View drawerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawarclass_layout);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerView = (View) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbaricons_layout, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.save:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

drawerclass_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapid"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="open.way.iscope.MyListFragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

actionbaricons_layout.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/category"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_select_all"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/categories"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/previous"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_previous_item"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/previous"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/next"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/save"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the drawer element is not the root element in your drawerclass_layout.xml. Make Drawer element as your root element and the map fragment as the child in the layout file and you will be able to see your slider over the top of the main fragment that has map. Here is the code snippet.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!-- google map -->
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Hope this would help!!